# Want to remove link from theme footer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to remove the link in WordPress theme footer. I have tried by removing the footer.php file code but it's not working. I'm using the theme [vantage](http://webstech.org/vantage-wordpress-theme/)

Answer (score 2):

There is two **footer.php** files one in the **main** directory and the other in the **parts** directory.

You need to delete this line from **footer.php** in the **parts** directory

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'vantage_footer_attribution', '<div id="theme-attribution">' . sprintf( __('A <a href="%s">SiteOrigin</a> Theme', 'vantage'), 'http://siteorigin.com') . '</div>' ) ?>
```

Comment: Hello @webstech and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark or up-voting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Open the site in the browser and inspect the page where the footer is present.
select the footer element and find the name of the selector used(id/class).
In the case of vantage theme, '**theme-attribution**' is the name of the selector used.

So to remove(hide) the footer text: 
Step 1: Log into your WordPress account.
Step 2: Go to Appearance.
Step 3: Under appearance select Custom CSS.
Step 4: In the text-area add the below CSS and hit save.
Step 5: Publish the changes and the footer will be hidden.

```
#theme-attribution{
visibility:hidden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace the footer.php in this parts folder under theme vantage theme with this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Part Name: Default Footer
 */
?>
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">

    <?php if( ! siteorigin_page_setting( 'hide_footer_widgets', false ) ) : ?>
        <div id="footer-widgets" class="full-container">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-footer' ) ?>
        </div><!-- #footer-widgets -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php $site_info_text = apply_filters('vantage_site_info', siteorigin_setting('general_site_info_text') ); if( !empty($site_info_text) ) : ?>
        <div id="site-info">
            <?php echo wp_kses_post($site_info_text) ?>
        </div><!-- #site-info -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    </footer><!-- #colophon .site-footer -->
```